# How to print elements of gsl::vector?

Tags: c++, gsl

I am debugging a third party code, while converting to mex file. They use gsl.

At one point, authors use:

```
gsl::vector_memcpy(&xtemp, _x);
```

and I would like to ensure that data was correctly copied. So, I would like to k ow how to print xtemp.

Another minor question:

When I searched online for gsl::vector_memcpy, I rather find gsl_vector_memcpy at
https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/vectors.html
Why the function name has been changed?

Comment: The name is essentially the same, I suppose that this is just a C++ wrapping for a C library.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured out the way to print out:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<5; i++)  std::cout<< xtemp.data[i] << std::endl;
```

Comment: But this is not the conventional way to access the elements of a vector.